# OTA update removed stock Contacts app (Galaxy Y S5360, Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread.XXMI1)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-y

My Galaxy Y S5360 did an OTA software update on 22 April 2014, and ever since then, after the phone rebooted, my Contacts app has gone completely!
The data is there, so I have had to download Contacts+ app from Google Play in order for me to call/text my contacts, but I can't add or edit any of my contacts.
I've contacted Carphonewarehouse, who I bought the phone from in January 2012, and they were unable to help. I've contacted Samsung, who got their remote assistance team to remotely delve into my phone (via Smart Tutor for Samsung app) and they were unable to help.
I've done a factory reset, no joy.
Apparently there is no option to reload the software update, as Kies is old and I can't update this because my phone is old and won't cope.
I am at a loss what to do!
I've raised a complaint with Samsung, so I'm hoping they will be sympathetic, but I won't hold my breathe.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

- download the required firmware bundle [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1465800)
- install Kies, or Samsung driver pack
- unzip the package, You'll get 3 *.tar (or tar.md5) files
- download Odin3 1.84 or 1.85
- stop Kies
- stop all active ADB sessions
- start odin
- do backup of your data and apps
- charge your SGY at least 75%
- remove SGY from USB or charger
- start the device in Download mode
- power off Your SGY
- wait 30 sec
- Press Vol Down, Home, and Power at the same time
- When (about 5 sec) Warning screen appears, release Volume Down and Power, then (a bit later) Home
- press Vol Up (You'll get Odin mode screen)
- Browse the 3 tar files to odin PDA=PDA_xxxx.tar, PHONE=MODEM_ or PHONE_xxxxx.tar, CSC=CSC_xxxxx.tar
- no PIT and/or BOOT files required - leave it empty!
- leave all other fields and checkboxes default!
- connect your phone, You must see yellow 0:[COMxx] in the first ID:COM and "Added" in the message box
- Start flashing by the START button.
- flashing will start immediately, see the progress in the message box, and progress bar on the phone
- Wait 1-3 minutes, until green PASS! in the upper left
- SGY will reboot, leave it as is for 2-5 minutes until startup finishes
- if it stuck (eg boot anim loop) then:

  ```
  - Start the phone in Recovery mode

  - remove battery
  - resinsert battery, wait 30 sec
  - press Vol Up, Home, Power at the same time
  - when Galaxy Y logo appears, release the Power button
  - when Recovery menu appears, release the Home button first, then finally Vol Up
  - select wipe data/factory reset (Vol UP/Down + Home)
  - select reboot system now
  ```

When Android boots up, it's highly recommended to set your CSC via the dialer *#272*_your_imei_# (to see IMEI type *#06# in dialer) -> (it will erase all your data on the phone, but not the SD card)

Comment: Thanks Ruben Roy, the thing is, I'm not a techie person and I'm worried I will screw this up - are there any other options?  I had palpatations just resetting the phone to factory settings ;-)

Comment: The only other option to reinstall the firmware is to give it to the service centre.

Comment: OK, many thanks. I'll wait to see what Samsung say before I do anything, hopefully they will accept it was their update that caused it and will recall the phone and reinstall the firmware at their service centre FOC.